# JSON pretty print without use json_decode in php

Tags: php, json

For example i have json strings like this ( from the first place ). And It's not formatted.

> {"data":[{"id":"14","memo_kondisi":"Kekurangan
>   pekerjaan","total_row":"5","nilai_temuan":"1.000.000","data_sebab":[{"id":"15","id_sebab":"","id_sub_sebab":"","memo_sebab":"coba","data_rekomendasi":[{"id":"25","id_rekomendasi":"10","id_sub_rekomendasi":"","id_s_sub_rekomendasi":"","nilai_rekomendasi":"0"},{"id":"26","id_rekomendasi":"10","id_sub_rekomendasi":"","id_s_sub_rekomendasi":"","nilai_rekomendasi":"0"},{"id":"31","id_rekomendasi":"10","id_sub_rekomendasi":"","id_s_sub_rekomendasi":"","nilai_rekomendasi":"0"}]},{"id":"16","id_sebab":"","id_sub_sebab":"","memo_sebab":"coba","data_rekomendasi":[{"id":"34","id_rekomendasi":"10","id_sub_rekomendasi":"","id_s_sub_rekomendasi":"","nilai_rekomendasi":"0"},{"id":"35","id_rekomendasi":"10","id_sub_rekomendasi":"","id_s_sub_rekomendasi":"","nilai_rekomendasi":"0"}]}]},{"id":"15","memo_kondisi":"Kekurangan
>   pekerjaan","total_row":"2","nilai_temuan":"1.000.000","data_sebab":[{"id":"5","id_sebab":"","id_sub_sebab":"","memo_sebab":"coba","data_rekomendasi":[]},{"id":"10","id_sebab":"","id_sub_sebab":"","memo_sebab":"coba","data_rekomendasi":[]}]},{"id":"16","memo_kondisi":"","total_row":"2","nilai_temuan":"0","data_sebab":[{"id":"9","id_sebab":"","id_sub_sebab":"","memo_sebab":"coba","data_rekomendasi":[]},{"id":"12","id_sebab":"","id_sub_sebab":"","memo_sebab":"coba","data_rekomendasi":[]}]}]}

I see some similar question that you have to use `json_decode` and i have to encode again and using `json_encode($json,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)`

Is there  a way for make json readable without decode the JSON first and encode it again in PHP ?

Note : **I expect the result is still in JSON**

Comment: Looks readable to me, it's just not formatted. Here is a formatter https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Not natively. Unless you're dealing with very large data it's not worth the effort to look for some alternative. And since I expect this is for debugging only anyway, it shouldn't be a big deal either way.

Comment: you can use online json parsers to just read your json data http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: oh i mean 'not formatted'

Comment: If this is only for debugging, which I expect it is, because there's no *functional* difference, I'd rather look into formatting JSON on the viewer side than worrying about it in PHP. E.g., there are browser plugins which pretty-print JSON responses for you if you want to debug in the browser…

Comment: @deceze i didn't know about that plugins. this  [one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) ?

Comment: Yup, for example that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a parser can understand the JSON, so you can either do what you proposed or write your own parser. If you have access to the origin of the JSON, make it pretty in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. Using someone else's parser lib won't make any difference, as they'll call `json_decode()` too.

You could create a little function that you could call:

```
function prettify($json)
{
    $array = json_decode($json, true);
    $json = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    return $json;
}
```

Then `echo prettify($jsonString);` would be easier than constantly decoding and re-encoding. See here https://3v4l.org/CcJlf

Comment: Well, you're still *decoding and re-encoding*, you're just hiding `json_encode(json_decode($json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)` behind a function call, which, meh… for something that you're hopefully not doing all that often as part of your regular code anyway doesn't make a whole lot of difference.

Comment: The point is, the answer is that it *isn't* possible, at least not without a LOT more coding.